# Authorization based on 'uncommentable' state of Video model

Tags: php, laravel, authorization

In my Laravel application I have a Video model that can have comments, and can be marked by admin in database to be in 'uncommentable' state, disabling new comments.

The implementation is simple - on the comment controllers 'store' action I check if Video has uncommentable property set, and if so I return 403 response with 'unauthorized' message.

Laravel documentation on authorization says that I should use policies or gates for handling authorization. But this logic is not related to any user, its just a state of the Video, in which it doesn't accept comments. So how can I use Policies to authorize a model without any relation to users?

Comment: You don't. That's unnecessary overkill, in my opinion. There's nothing wrong with the action you're taking. Although, I think hiding the comment box all together on video's that are **uncommentable** is an alternative.

Comment: I see, well if it's not uncommon to return authorization responses directly from actions, then I'll use that.